# How to programmatically append an error to a FormGroup control?

Tags: angular, typescript, validation

In my dynamic FormGroup I would like to programmatically append an error to a form control, but the only way I see to add an error is like this

```
this.userForm.controls.username.setErrors({
  'exists': 'Username already exists'
});
```

Which completely replaces any existing errors. Is there any way to append a single error to a dynamic FormGroup control?

Comment: The more idiomatic way is to do this in a [`Validator`](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators), which handles problem this for you. Probably in your case, you want an [`AsyncValidator`](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#async-validation), since you have to check your BE for the usrename. Is there a reason you have to do it this way?

Comment: @msanford No reason I necessarily have to do it his way. Just more of a curiosity thing as this was my initial approach and noticed the api didn't seem to accommodate what I was trying to do. Thanks for the idea about the AsyncValidator!

Comment: I was considering elaborating an answer showing how to use it, but the doc I linked it actually quite sufficient. Take a look at those, it will be a _little bit_ of a learning curve, but it's _much_ nicer to deal with in the long run.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
control.setErrors({ ...(control.errors || {}), 'newError': 'text of the error' })
```

You just have to get the previous errors and spread them into your new error object.

```
control.errors || {}
```

Is a protection against non-spreadable values (for instance, undefined or null)

Answer (score 1):

Use spread operator

```
const errors = this.userForm.controls.username.errors || {};
this.userForm.controls.username.setErrors({
  'exists': 'Username already exists', ...errors
})
```

Comment: With respect, this is equivalent but arguably inferior to the existing answer (as it creates an assignment).

Comment: @msanford and as per the best practices of stack overflow, consider upvoting the answer that is similar to yours, instead of parroting it. This prevents questions overloading and doesn't seem like you're phishing for reputation.